# How to connect a Flask Back-end app to Flask Front-end app?

Tags: python, web, flask, frontend, backend

I've developed a Python Flask Back-end app which allows me to do some HTTP requests on a Jsonfile (a sort of database) such as GET (to see a list of items) or POST (to create a new item in the Json database). Until now, I used Postman to test my app and all worked well. However, I'd like to develop a Python Flask Front-end app in order to create a graphical interface (in a web browser with jinja templates) to do the same requests. The problem is, I don't know how to begin my new app, I've googled all my questions but found no answer...

How can we "link" front-end and back-end apps in order to get the information from the web brower, make the requests via the back-end and then send the response with the front-end?

Comment: On the frontend you will need to play a little with html/css for the markup and style and use javascript/ajax to perform the requests to the backend app. You don't necessarily need a flask app to serve your frontend application (you could use react or another javascript framework for this purpose), but it should also work.

Comment: And have you ever used Flask to serve a backend application ?

Answer (score 3):

**Using RESTful API.**

A infrastructure solution could be (a classic one):

- Your app server listening on 5000. It uses the REST architectural.
- Your frontend server listening on 80/443. It makes requests to your app server to get the data and fill your html template with this data. The requests can be made with a library like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). *The requests library is one of the simpliest but you can choose another one to make HTTP requests.*

**Workflow:**

> Client <-HTTP requests-> Frontend <-HTTP requests made with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)->
>   App Server <--> Database

**Advantage:**
One of the advantage of this architecture: you can easily duplicate your servers or having multiple app servers responsible of different tasks. They can be running on the same machine or separated machines.

**Serving static files:**

If you are talking about serving static files for the frontend, then you should use an existing Webserver like Nginx (html/css/js files).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So to begin, all I have to do is doing some requests with the library requests on the URL of my backend app to test ?

Comment: Yes, this is how most of the web services work nowadays.